# How to read dictionary input into snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have input fastq files inside dictionary. I want to access it inside snakemake. Could anyone please suggest me how I can access it?

Here is the code that I've tried so far.

```
infile_loc = {"Sample1":["/home/joshua/snakemake_works/input/Sample1_R1.fq.gz","/home/joshua/snakemake_works/input/Sample1_R2.fq.gz"], "Sample2":["/home/joshua/snakemake_works/input/Sample2_R1.fq.gz","/home/joshua/snakemake_works/input/Sample2_R2.fq.gz"]}

SAMPLES=infile_loc.keys()

rule print_file_name:
    input:
        expand("{sample}", sample=SAMPLES)
    params:
        read1, read2 = lambda wildcards: infile_loc[wildcards.sample]
    script:
        """
        echo {params.read1}
        echo {params.read2}
        """
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
NameError in file /home/joshua/snakemake_works/Snakefile, line 9:
name 'read1' is not defined
  File "/home/joshua/snakemake_works/Snakefile", line 9, in <module>
```

Could anyone please guide me how I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you use the `script` directive, and you should use the `shell` directive instead.

```
rule print_file_name:
    input:
        expand("{sample}", sample=SAMPLES)
    params:
        read1, read2 = lambda wildcards: infile_loc[wildcards.sample]
    shell:  # <------- script changed to shell
        """
        echo {params.read1}
        echo {params.read2}
        """
```

Comment: Thank you @Maarten-vd-Sande for pointing out the error. I've changed script to shell, but I'm still getting error. I've posted the modified code above.